# Factoring a multivariate polynomial.

Tags: polynomials, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

Let $P(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in \mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ a polynomial in complex $n$-variables. There is a method to find out if this polynomial can be written as
$$P(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=m(x_1)\ldots m(x_n)$$
with $m(x)$ a polynomial in one variable?

Comment: Observing $P(x,y)=x^2+y^2=(x+iy)(x-iy)$, we found out that the claim is not valid always.

Answer (score 0):

The polynomial has the seprated form
$$P(x_1,\dots,x_n) = p_1(x_1)\cdots p_n(x_n), $$
if and only if the PDE
$$P^{n-1}\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x_1 \cdots \partial x_n} P =  \frac{\partial P}{\partial x_1} \cdots \frac{\partial P}{\partial x_n} $$
holds.
Conditional on that fact, you may also check whether the polynomial is invariant under all permutations in $S_n$.